# How to use ThreadSafeClientConnManager.requestConnection(HttpRoute route, Object state)

Tags: android, apache

With ThreadSafeClientConnManager.requestConnection(HttpRoute route, Object state), what is the second item "state" supposed to be?

Ultimately I'm trying to ThreadSafeClientConnManager.releaseConnection(ManagedClientConnection conn, long validDuration, TimeUnit timeUnit) to release the connection. But I need the ManagedClientConnection, which is only available from the requestConnection method (via the returned ClientConnectionRequest)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should be able to safely pass null for the state parameter.

DefaultRequestDirector calls requestConnection like so...

```
Object userToken = context.getAttribute(ClientContext.USER_TOKEN);

// Allocate connection if needed
if (managedConn == null) {
    ClientConnectionRequest connRequest = connManager.requestConnection(route, userToken);
```

Further up the chain, if context is null (as it is when you call client.execute(httpRequest)), context is replaced by a default context, which does not contain a USER_TOKEN, so requestConnection is called with null for the state parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fairly decent example on how to use this class (see link at bottom). Turns out `releaseConnection()` is not required, if you do a `entity.consumeContent()` on the response. Also make sure to pass in BasicHttpContext in to httpclient.execute.

Similar to this:

```
this.context = new BasicHttpContext();

httpclient.execute(httppost,context);
String entityStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
response.getEntity().consumeContent();
```

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java

Still no idea what "state" is inside of requestConnection: `ThreadSafeClientConnManager.requestConnection(HttpRoute route, Object state)`